# Updated Timestamp field in MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table in mysql with a field that is of "TIMESTAMP" type. I need help writing the SQL query to update the field with the current timestamp.

```
UPDATE tb_Test set dt_modified = ?????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE tb_Test 
   SET dt_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 WHERE ? -- if you don't specify, ALL dt_modified values will be updated
```

You can use `NOW()` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is ANSI standard so the query can be ported to other databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tb_Test MODIFY COLUMN dt_modified TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Now whenever any field is changed the `dt_modified`  will be updated by the special trigger.